# Replace a number followed by a tab with keeping the number and adding a second tab using REGEX in Notepad++

Tags: regex, tabs, notepad++

I have a file with this appearence:

```
399 MISC    KAK/BAR  0     0    0   0   0   0           
2   FOO     BAR      FOO   0    0   0   0   0   0
```

***where each space is a tab in practice***

I want to remove all tabs in the string, so I can later import the file into Excel using a `tab delimiter`.

For this my thought is to replace each number ending with a tab with keeping the number, but adding an additional tab. Then I want to

`replace \t with` (i.e one blank step)

For the first step, to add an additional tab behind each number ending a sequence I've tried to use the following `Replace` using `REGEX`:

```
Search for ^[\0-9]\t
Replace with $0\t
```

This however only works when I have a single number, and only if it occurs in the first column. In my example it becomes:

```
399\tMISC\tKAK/BAR\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0            
2\t\tFOO\tBAR\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0
```

but I want it to become:

```
399\t\tMISC\tKAK/BAR\t0\t\t0\t\t0\t\t0\t\t0\t\t0            
2\t\tFOO\tBAR\t0\t\t0\t\t0\t\t0\t\t0
```

i.e. a double tab after each `number sequence`. In my later output I included the tabs as `\t` as I Believe it was rather hard to determine whether it was a double or single tab when I wrote the **actual output**.

Does anyonw know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Then try `[0-9]\t` -> `$0\t` - why use `^`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How stupid of me. Then it worked. I'm new with REGEX and searched through a bunch of examples. Please consider posting your comment as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex replacement:

*Find What*:     `[0-9]\t`
*Replace With*: `$0\t`

The `^` caret is a start of line anchor in NPP, and it will only let you pattern match if there is one digit at the start of a line that has a tab after it. So, `[0-9]\t` will match any 1 digit and a `\t` after it *anywhere* on a line.

**Details**:

- `[0-9]` - matches any ASCII digit
- `\t` - a tab
- `$0` - a backreference referencing to the whole matched text

Comment: Thanks for adding additional information. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
Search:  \d+\t
Replace: $0\t
```

The expression `\d+` matches any (uninterrupted) string of digits, such as `01446`. Notepad++ 6.0 or newer ships with built-in [PCRE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) support.